# Does Join Order matter performance

Tags: sql

```
create table Employee(

id int identity(1,1) primary key,
Username varchar(50),
FirstName varchar(50),
LastName varchar(50),
DepartID int

) 
create table Departments(

id int identity(1,1) primary key,
DepartmentName varchar(50)

)
```

Both Join result set is same we get Employee matching and non matching.

```
Select * from Employee E
Left Join 
Departments D
ON  D.ID= E.DepartID 

Select * from  Departments D
Right Join  Employee E 
ON E.DepartID  =D.ID
```

Comment: As `a LEFT b` is the same as `b RIGHT a` there should be no difference.

Comment: Tag dbms used. Performance questions are almost always product specific!

Answer (score 1):

Both of your query are indeed completely interchangeable. And should be no difference in performance nor result.

Most people only use `LEFT JOIN` since it seems more intuitive, and it's universal syntax - I don't think all RDBMS support `RIGHT JOIN`. Not all RDBMSs support SQL. For example, SQLite 3 doesn't implement `RIGHT` and `FULL OUTER JOIN`.